# Get Category Of Product WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I try to get the category of an item, it shows like this

[image]

The code I am using is `$product->get_categories()`

I need to get output 'Hoodies'

Thanks for your time.

Edit : Full code added

```
<script>
   console.log('<?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?>')
</script>
```

The code is on the Product Page, note: I am getting all other values (name, price ..etc) correctly.

Comment: Can you share your code on how you got this thing?

Comment: Do you just need the categories' names without anchor tags?

Comment: Yes @VijayHardaha

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$categories = $product->get_categories();
echo strip_tags($categories);
```